# No enrollment ID or enrollment secret has been provided

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm using the RESTful API to communicate to the ledger. I've added some protection to the API by using Passport.

Now I'd like to issue an identity to a specific participant in the network. The CLI command works just fine.

`composer identity issue -n 'epd' -i admin -s adminpw -u "myid" -a "nl.epd.blockchain.Patient#myid"`

But whenever I try to use the RESTful API call it keeps saying:

> No enrollment ID or enrollment secret has been provided

The payload I am sending looks like the following

```
{
  "participant": "nl.epd.blockchain.Patient#myid",
  "userID": "myid",
  "options": {
    "enrollmentID" : "admin",
    "enrollmentSecret" : "adminpw"
   }
}
```

To startup the REST server I use the following code:

```
composer-rest-server -n epd -p defaultProfile -i admin -s adminpw -N never -P 3000 -S true
```

So I guess my payload is incorrect because it can't find the enrollmentid and secret. So what's the correct format for the payload?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the enrollmentID and enrollmentSecret as part of the payload. Those get passed in via the `composer-rest-server`.

Here are some instructions on enabling REST authentication for a business network. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html

I think the step you are missing is `Adding a Blockchain identity to the default wallet`

Comment: I did complete all these steps.  But that chapter assumes a Blockchain identity is already added to the network. It doesn't explain how to create an identity. Only how to set it.  "This example will assume that you have issued the Blockchain identity alice1 to the participant org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant#alice@email.com"

Comment: Adding participants and issuing identities is described in the docs here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/managing/participantsandidentities.html